# App crash in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

How to handled the unhandled exception in winrt windows phone 8.1 app. It display only the following exception name in output window

```
The program '[7560] MyApp.exe' has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
```

and some time it Displayed

```
The thread 0x552c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x4440 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1560 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1f04 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1f30 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

With this I can't get anything about the app crash in output window. How to find this exception or how to handled to solve this exception, After this exception the app has been closed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 0xc0000409 = STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN - The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in  this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.use remote debugging to steps into the code until you find the part where it crashes

Comment: I suggest switching to "native debugging" in the debugger settings. The crash is clearly happening in native code. Managed debugged just cannot break there.

Answer (score 2):

use try catch block or create custom error handler on your app.xml.cs file..

Comment: But still app crashed and closed some times.

Comment: please find out where you are getting app crashed and make sure you are getting null values.